# How much PHP do I need to know in order to create new modules?

Tags: 7

I don't really have much php knowledge but would like to be able to create custom modules. Will this be possible? Or have I got no chance?

Comment: PHP is an essential part of module development. Without that it would be difficult to make a module.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any tips on the best and quickest ways to learn PHP?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp this would be good starting point

Comment: w3schools is a *horrible* resource. It is blight. http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/)